# The Y-axis on my XVICO X3 seems to run backwards. I can't level or home the printer. What can I do to fix it?

Tags: y-axis

I purchased the XVICO X3 over a year ago. It had fair reviews. I didn't end up assembling the printer until recently.

The Y-axis appears to run backwards, so I can't use it for anything. It jams the print plate and I have to manually cut it off. Tried everything with no luck. I have considered replacing the board. The frame and parts are nice.  Overall, it looks like it would be a great printer and some YouTube videos say as much for the price. Some articles suggest running Marlin 2.0 by flashing the board, as the XVICO X3 printer is an Ender styled machine. If the board is flawed, I think it would be useless to try that.

I'm clueless and would appreciate any help provided.  Support from Xvico is hard to get.

Comment: More specific information is needed. Consider to use a manual control resource (terminal mode in a slicer) to command the steppers in a desired direction. If you discover that a stepper is reversed, you can swap control wires to reverse direction or flip movement in the firmware.

Comment: You tried everything, what specifically? Stepper direction is a matter of pulling the connector of the Y stepper flip it 180° and push it back in.

Comment: Hi @Oscar, I've tried everything a clueless person knows to do, kicked it, ran over it, cussed it, and messed with every setting in the UI.  I thought the connector ends only fit one way.  If so, do I cut the wires?  Which of the four wires should I swap?